# Same route different middleware route group

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

Here is my super admin middleware,

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

and,here is admin middleware,

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 2) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

Here is my manager middleware,

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 3) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

Here is my seller middleware,

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 4) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

and, this is web.php,

```php
Route::middleware(['superadmin'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    //and more
});
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    //and more
});
Route::middleware(['manager'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('managers', ManagerController::class);
    //and more
});
Route::middleware(['seller'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('sellers', SellersController::class);
    //and more
});
```

I have 4types of middleware. Each route group have different route. Its working properly. Some of the routes are also used in another group. But then it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have also another middleware too,,,and I want only these two of middleware are use this route,

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Please try to provide more details by editing the question like: If logged in user is **admin** - do this and if logged in user is **superadmin** - do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't make sense to have two different middleware here. What do you want to achieve? If the user is an **admin** then what and if user is a **superadmin** then what?

If the purpose is to just allow either **admin** or **superadmin** to access routes defined under the middleware group then a single middleware is enough.

```php
//IsAdmin middleware
//if the user is either superadmin or admin allow else redirect
if(in_array(Auth::user()->role_id, [1,2])) {

    //If you want to process based on whether admin or superadmin
    //you can do it here
    //if(Auth::user()->role_id ===1) {
    //    process when user is superadmin
    // }
    //else {
    //    process when user is admin
    //}
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

Then protect the routes in routes file

```php
Route::middleware(['isAdmin'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

});
```

Comment: I have also another middleware too,,,and I want only these two of middleware are use this route,

Comment: @e_mon You can apply any number of middleware to the routes. If the middleware is used to check if a logged in user is admin or super admin you should do it in single middleware. Even if you want to do different set of things depending on whether the user is admin or superadmin.

Comment: now I write full code... now tell me.

Comment: @e_mon `Route::resource('users', UserController::class);` generates same routes in both groups - under middleware **admin** as well as **superadmin** . Please ensure that each route is defined only once in routes file. If you have multiple different middleware to be applied, define the routes individually with middleware. Eg: `Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->middleware(['web', 'isAdmin']);`